# How to say "calendar" in Chinese?

Tags: translation, grammar

In English, calendar can refer to several things. I would like the Chinese word that would mean calender in the sense of a planner, like how a teacher might calender her future lesson plans or you might calendar your meetings tomorrow. 谢谢！

Comment: 安排一下 / 安排上了 sounds natural to me

Answer (score 3):

Mainland China: 日程表 (literally *day schedule table*)

ROC (Taiwan): 行事曆 (literally *matter attendance calendar*)

These are both nouns, of course. It is impossible to use these as verbs like the examples specified in the question. In Chinese, you would properly say the equivalent of *recording (some event X) in the calendar*:

> 把Ｘ［記錄・加入・添］在［日程表・行事曆］中

Comment: I found it's pretty common that nouns are used as verbs in English. I think the use of 'calendar' in OP's examples is ok. But I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: @dan I just checked a dictionary, and you're right...you can use it as a verb. Never heard it being used this way in my life, though.

Answer (score 3):

"calendar" can be 把...排进日程表. "calendar your meetings" could be 把会议排进日程表.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is more appropriate you call them schedule.

- School schedule : 课程表
- Touring plan : 行程表
- bus schedule : 巴士行程表
- Cleaning delegation schedule : 清扫值勤表